# How to get selected node from JTree after selecting it?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JTree: how to get the text of selected item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240074/jtree-how-to-get-the-text-of-selected-item)

1In C# there's [TreeView_afterSelect event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.afterselect(v=vs.71).aspx), and i ask if in java is something like that ? I used : `hierarchyPropertyChange` but it runs two times...

Comment: It seems this has already been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240074/jtree-how-to-get-the-text-of-selected-item), even nice code example included.

Answer (score 9):

You can use a `TreeSelectionListener`:

```
tree.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {

@Override
public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
   DefaultMutableTreeNode selectedNode = 
       (DefaultMutableTreeNode)tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent(); 
   ...          
  }
});
```

Comment: If this is the first click in the tree, the tree will return a NullPointer. So this does not work for the first click in a tree.

Comment: @Nina Are you sure? It works for me on the first click. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#getLastSelectedPathComponent-- says `Returns the last path component of the selected path.` It does *not* say "get the path that was selected previously."