# Java JTree get name of selected node

Tags: java, swing, jtree, treenode

I would like to find out how to get the name of the selected node in a JTree, not the userObject which is the text of the treenode.

I have manually created several tree nodes and I need to determine which one is selected by the node's name.

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root"); 
DefaultMutableTreeNode node1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Hey it's node1!");
DefaultMutableTreeNode node2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Hey, it's node2!");
root.add(node1); root.add(node2);
```

Now, based on that, I need to know if node1 or node2 is selected. I want a return value of node1 or node2 (variable name).

To make this more clear: I have a JFrame, with a JPanel, a JScrollPane, a JTree, and some text fields. Depending on which node is clicked (node 1, or node 2), I want to show or hide certain text fields.

Comment: What do you mean by "name" of the node? Won't this depend on how your node object is structured? What have you tried and how isn't it working?

Comment: DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");
DefaultMutableTreeNode node1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Hey it's node1!");

DefaultMutableTreeNode node2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Hey, it's node2!");

root.add(node1);
root.add(node2);

Now, based on that, I need to know if node1 or node2 is selected. I want a return value of node1 or node2.

Comment: OK,..... so again, what do you mean by "name"? Variable names have little significance and less utility if that's what you mean.

Comment: Yes, i want the variable name of the node

Comment: Ugh, please post code as an edit to your original post, and format it (check the help link for this), but not in comments since it is unreadable in comments. So again, please edit your question. Also tell us why you want a variable name, what you plan to do with it? Why not instead override DefaultMutableTreeNode and give it a String name field?

Comment: This is a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/155831).

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Amen! He doesn't realize that variable names are close to meaningless, that many variables don't even have "names", that an object can be referenced by 2, 3, 100, ... variables. The question makes no sense. He must delineate what problem he's trying to solve, not how he's trying to solve it, for surely he's going about it the wrong way.

Comment: I have a JFrame, with a JPanel, a JScrollPane, a JTree, and some text fields. Depending on which node is clicked (node 1, or node 2), I want to show or hide certain text fields. That is what I am attempting to accomplish.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/155831) that the OP seems unwilling or unable to expand upon.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - I am uncertain as what explanation you are looking for. I have expanded upon it as best I can.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240074/jtree-how-to-get-the-text-of-selected-item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I wanted my Node to have a name, I'd extend the base class, here DefaultMutableTreeNode, and give it a String name field, and then fill that field with a value via a constructor, one that takes both a String name parameter and a String text parameter. And then also give it a getter method.

I wouldn't try to get its "variable" name since that is close to Meaningless. Many variables don't even have "names", that an object can be referenced by 2, 3, 100, ... variables.

---

**Edit**
You state in an edit:

> To make this more clear: I have a JFrame, with a JPanel, a JScrollPane, a JTree, and some text fields. Depending on which node is clicked (node 1, or node 2), I want to show or hide certain text fields.

Again, variable names are close to meaningless and almost don't exist in compiled code. What counts are variable *references* -- being able to grab a variable, and object *state* -- the state of the fields held by that variable.

Comment: Thank you! Hovercraft Full Of Eels - Your idea to override the constructor and add the set/get name methods is what I needed. I appreciate your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Kind of old that thread, but in my opinion you do not have to derive any class. When you initialize a DefaultMutableTreeNode object with the optional parameter userObj, you can get this parameter again by calling getUserObject(). See the api for further information: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html

I think is is pretty much what you are searching for - at least I was searching for it.